# PHP Array, echo specific ID

Tags: php

I am new in PHP and I want to print specific id from array. If you could help me how it should looks, i really apprecea it.

```
$playersStr = "7656654642192473"
              "8686868682192473";

$players = array();             

$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=2987978A4898+2F66hfhfht17FE4&steamids=$playersStr";
$json_object= file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player)
{
    $players[$player->steamid]['personaname'] = $player->personaname;
}
```

So the question is how I can print both of these? First and second.

```
echo $players[$player->steamid]['personaname'] = $player->personaname; //first
echo $players[$player->steamid]['personaname'] = $player->personaname; //second
```

Comment: You already have a `foreach` loop, just add an `echo` to the line inside the loop?

Comment: What is `$playersStr` for? It's not valid syntax, should it be an array like `$playersStr = ["7656654642192473",
              "8686868682192473"];`?

Comment: That dosn't solve anything, I want to print that specific $playerStr, like first or second array

Comment: it would help if we could see an example of the JSON being downloaded. Also how is `$playersStr` relevant in the code? You don't seem to be using it. Are you wanting to compare the values from $playersStr (which as Barmar correctly says, you need to make into an array first, because at the moment it's nonsense) with the steam IDs from the JSON, and only print specific ones? Your question really is not very clear unfortunately.

Comment: hm someone edited that

Comment: yes, people can edit your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit. Usually it's done to improve the quality of it. In this case it was done because you had a very obvious typo. Check the history here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61601259/revisions . You can also edit your own question, of course.

Comment: So any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: using an `==` comparison?? It's not really clear where you're stuck, exactly. If you want to compare the values, start by writing a simple `if` statement to compare them.

Comment: Still didn't solved, any ideas?

Comment: Well you need to update your question and show us what code you tried. I don't know precisely what you did, therefore I can't tell you why it didn't fully solve the issue. We are not mind-readers. Also as requested earlier please show a sample of the JSON data, and show clearly what output you want from your code. It's not still 100% clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $key=>$player){
       print_r($key)
}
```

Comment: And what should be key value?

Comment: This should be enumerated key from the range (size) of array or objects that you have

Comment: Still I can't understand how it should work? Can you give me full example of it?